# Slice string into groups of 3 with overlaps

Tags: python, string, indexing, slice

I have been trying to slice a string into groups of three with overlaps.

For example, `'abcdefg'` to `'abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def', 'efg'`

My current code is:

```
s = 'abcdefg'
[s[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]
```

But that only returns me `'abc'`, `'def'`, `'g'`.

How do I change it so that I can have the overlaps? I want it to be able to do this for any string length.

Comment: Try: `[s[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(s)-2)]`

Comment: What do you want to happen with a source string of length less than 3?

Comment: @alfasin  brilliant but what if i want to split `abcdef` into `[abcd,cdef]`

Comment: @SIslam that's a totally different question than the one the OP posted! for that you can simply do `s[0:4], s[-4:]`

Answer (score 2):

You could change your list comprehension to:

```
>>> [s[i:i+3] for i in range(len(s)-2)]
['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def', 'efg']
```

At the moment you're taking steps of 3 (not 1) so you don't get the overlap. You also want to stop `i` two places before the end of the string (or you'll get the shorter substrings `'fg'` and `'g'`, too), so take `2` from the length of the string.